# C#: Error in getting device instance handle

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, device-instance-id

In my C# code I am trying to use C++ functions: `CM_Locate_DevNodeW` and `CM_Open_DevNode_Key` (using [pinvoke](https://pinvoke.net/)).
My code seems something like this:

```
String deviceId = "PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_591B&SUBSYS_22128086&REV_01\\3&11583659&0&10";
int devInst = 0;
cmStatus = CM_Locate_DevNodeW(&devInst, deviceId, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL);
if (cmStatus == CR_SUCCESS)
{
    UIntPtr pHKey = new UIntPtr();
    cmStatus = CM_Open_DevNode_Key(devInst, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, 0, RegDisposition_OpenExisting, pHKey, CM_REGISTRY_SOFTWARE);
    if (cmStatus == CR_SUCCESS)
    {
        //but here cmStatus=3 (Invalid Pointer)
    }
}
```

After calling to `CM_Locate_DevNodeW`, the `devInst` becomes `1`, and the `cmStatus` is 0 = `CR_SUCCESS`. But the call to `CM_Open_DevNode_Key` fails.
I don't know if `CM_Locate_DevNodeW` returns `CR_SUCCESS` but puts incorrect data within `devInst`? ('1' does not seems like real device instance handle...)

Or maybe the call to `CM_Open_DevNode_Key` is wrong?

I declared the functions like this:

```
[DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern unsafe int CM_Locate_DevNodeW(
    int* pdnDevInst,  
    string pDeviceID, 
    ulong ulFlags);

[DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern unsafe int CM_Open_DevNode_Key(
     int dnDevNode,
     int samDesired,
     int ulHardwareProfile,
     int Disposition,
     IntPtr phkDevice,
     int ulFlags);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `CM_Locate_DevNodeW` isn't a `C++` function. It's a `C` function provided by the Windows API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fiddled around with your code and this is what I've got so far. After reading some docs I found out that `phkDevice` parameter of `CM_Open_DevNode_Key` function was likely an `out` parameter so I updated function signature

```
[DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern unsafe int CM_Open_DevNode_Key(
    int dnDevNode,
    int samDesired,
    int ulHardwareProfile,
    int Disposition,
    out IntPtr phkDevice, //added out keyword
    int ulFlags);
```

And I tried to run the following code

```
IntPtr pHKey;

string deviceId = @"my keyboard pci id";
int devInst = 0;
int cmStatus = CM_Locate_DevNodeW(&devInst, deviceId, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL);
if (cmStatus == CR_SUCCESS)
{
    int opencmStatus = CM_Open_DevNode_Key(devInst, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, 0, RegDisposition_OpenExisting, out pHKey, CM_REGISTRY_SOFTWARE);
    if (opencmStatus == CR_SUCCESS)
    {
        // 
    }
}
```

I got `opencmStatus` `51` which corresponds to `CR_ACCESS_DENIED`. Then I thought "*Hmm, don't I just requesting to much access? Let's try only read access options*" So I replaced `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` with `1` (`KEY_QUERY_VALUE`) and ran the following code

```
IntPtr pHKey;

string deviceId = @"my keyboard pci id";
int devInst = 0;
int cmStatus = CM_Locate_DevNodeW(&devInst, deviceId, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL);
if (cmStatus == CR_SUCCESS)
{
    int opencmStatus = CM_Open_DevNode_Key(devInst, 1, 0, RegDisposition_OpenExisting, out pHKey, CM_REGISTRY_SOFTWARE);
    if (opencmStatus == CR_SUCCESS)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

It worked as expected. Finally, this version gave me `opencmStatus` equals to `0`.

I did all tests against my keyboard PCI identifier, dont know if it matters.

Comment: Adding the `out` keyword was enough for solving my issue. I didn't get `CR_ACCESS_DENIED` even when using `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`, maybe this is because my app is running with Administrator privilege. 
Thanks for your quick and efficient support!